# Suitable static FBML app replacement

Tags: html, css, facebook, static

Now that Facebook is deprecating FBML does anyone know how I would get Facebook to still host the HTML/CSS inside these FBML tabs/ apps?

I found an app called [Static HTML](http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?api_key=190322544333196). This app is great but I'd much rather Facebook host my HTML/ CSS than a third party.

Thanks in advanced! :)
Smccullough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think facebook will...

You can get a free hosting plans at loads of places, complete with php support and mysql... for example host-ed.net gives free hosting, and so does many of other hosts. just google it.

EDIT

a recommended solution is:
http://x10hosting.com/